# How to repair a specific table in prod database

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

I have a production database in which I have multiple tables. There is one table in which I store the server responses for the API calls which I receive.

Now that particular table is not working properly. I mean, the data is getting added into that table.

When I click on info button of the table, am getting the details which include number of rows and all. I can see that it's increasing. But the problem is that, whenever I try to execute any query on that table, my MySql workbench crashes.

I tried `repair table indoor.ServerResponse;` but again this query also doesn't work. It keeps on running and somewhere down the line, it freezes.

I just have few thousand rows in that table.

Now my question is :

1) How do I repair the table ? Did I lose it all?

2) How do I make sure that this doesn't happen in future? As this is the prod database.

3) I am also not able to Alter other tables in the database. But the queries run fine. Why is it so?

P.S. Am using MySql workbench.

Comment: What did you do on that table first?

Comment: Nothing really. It was working fine yesterday.

Comment: Do you have an updated back up?

Comment: Could you dump your db and restore it to another new database then try to find out what's going on? You can try it to another PC also

Comment: **Slow down.** You have not yet said anything here that suggests that there is really a problem with the table or the server.  Describe the crash.  Screen shots and error messages.  The problem may be in Workbench itself.  Access the server with a different client, such as the `mysql` command line client, HeidiSQL, etc.  Don't start tinkering with the server or the data at this point.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, there are no error messages per say. I installed HeidiSQL right now. It too says no rows. Last night when I checked it, there were rows in there. But now in HeidiSQL, it shows that there are no rows. But while inspecting the table in workbench, it shows me that there are rows in it.